# Angular 6 - How do I Clone/Duplicate a div in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, clone

I am working on a project that involves providing information on vehicle components. Each component has a set of descriptive fields. I have an "Add another component" button that needs to create an identical div container with the same fields. The cloned parent div will need a different ID of course. For example:

In the component html file:

```
<div id="component-outer">
    <div class="component-inner">
         Component Content....
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="clone()">Add Another Component</div>
```

In the component ts file:

```
export class AppComponent {
    clone(){
         Need to clone #component-outer div and append below the last instance 
         of that div, then append the div name on the cloned element.
    }
}
```

I am accustomed to using javascript/jQuery to clone elements, but having trouble finding the best approach to EXACTLY what I am trying to accomplish in Angular. Is cloning the right approach?

Comment: You should clone an item in your model, and have your HTML bind to a list.  You should not manipulate the DOM directly in Angular apps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `*ngFor` to create DOM elements for each item in an array.

```
<div id="component-outer">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="component-inner">
         Component Content....
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="append()">Add Another Component</div>

export class AppComponent {
     public items: any[];

     public append() {
          this.items.push({
              // values depend on what an item is
          });
     }
}
```

This is covered in the documentation in the *first* chapter of the *first* tutorial.

https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor